# How to get folder in directory by part of the name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to figure out how to get the name of a folder in certain directory, but the folder name I need is generated randomly, but its name always ends in `.user` (for example the folder could be 1245fa.user or WRf5.user).
How can I do that?

Here is how I am getting a folder with a name that never changes

```
string slug = @"%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\MyApp\Profiles\constantuser\";
string filePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(slug);
string targetPath = @"C:\ErrorLog";
string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath, p);
string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, p);
```

In this case I would need the `constantuser`  to be the folder that ends with .user

Comment: You could use `.Contains(".user")` on the folder name. But if you've got multiples, that won't work very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `Where()` (or `First()`, `Single()`, ...) LINQ extensions on `Directory.EnumerateDirectories()`.

Assuming the following code (note the slug ending in the "parent" directory):

```
var slug = @"%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\MyApp\Profiles\";
var parentDirectoy = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(slug);
```

If you know *for sure* there's exactly one directory matching the criterion, you can do this:

```
var directoryName = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(parentDirectory)
                              .SingleOrDefault(dir => dir.EndsWith(".user"));
if (directoryName != null) 
{
    // do your thing
}
```

If you use `Single` instead of `SingleOrDefault`, a missing directory or more than one directory will result in an Exception instead of returning `null`.

If there may be multiple directories, you can do this instead:

```
var directoryNames = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(parentDirectory)
                              .Where(dir => dir.EndsWith(".user"));
foreach (var directoryName in directoryNames) 
{
    // do your thing
}
```

Where the loop may either run zero times if no matches are found or multiple times; one for each match.

Comment: what will happen if there are more than one folders with that name, can you please edit your answer to include a for loop?

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer I though it would be obvious, but here you go.

Comment: I am just new at C# and don't know the syntax very well, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(filePath, "*.user")
```